# Cannot sudo apt-get -f install because of jdk problem

Tags: 14.04, updates, software-installation, java, openjdk

I am completely stumped. The problem is as follows.

```
user@mycomputer:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
   openjdk-7-jdk
Suggested packages:
  visualvm
The following packages will be upgraded:
  openjdk-7-jdk
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 322 not upgraded.
85 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/16.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 348 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or     without a controlling terminal.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Selecting previously unselected package openjdk-7-jdk:i386.
(Reading database ... 258923 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-7-jdk_7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-7-jdk:i386 (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) over (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jdk_7u71-2.5.3-    0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/src.zip', which is also in     package openjdk-7-source 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jdk_7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't know what to delete/remove. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT #1**

Adding output from Charles Green's suggestion because it's impossible to read in the comment.

```
user@mycomputer:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge openjdk-7-source
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-7-jdk : Depends: openjdk-7-jre (= 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1) but 7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

**EDIT #2**

Charles Smith's second suggestion.

```
user@mycomputer:~$ sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jdk_7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb
(Reading database ... 258923 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-7-jdk_7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-7-jdk:i386 (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) over (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/src.zip', which is also in package openjdk-7-source 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-7-jdk:i386:
 openjdk-7-jdk:i386 depends on openjdk-7-jre (= 7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1); however:
  Package openjdk-7-jre:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openjdk-7-jdk:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openjdk-7-jdk:i386
```

However, if I try to `sudo apt-get -f install`, I still get an error.

**EDIT 3**

```
user@mycomputer:~$ sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jre_7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jre_7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jre_7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb
```

**EDIT 4**

```
user@mycomputer:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i openjdk-7-jre_7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb 
(Reading database ... 258922 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack openjdk-7-jre_7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-7-jre:i386 (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) over (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-7-jre:i386:
 openjdk-7-jre:i386 depends on openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1); however:
  Package openjdk-7-jre-headless:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openjdk-7-jre:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openjdk-7-jre:i386
```

Comment: Can you try `sudo apt-get remove --purge openjdk-7-source`, then followed by `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: I can't remove it.

`user@mycomputer:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge openjdk-7-source`

`[sudo] password for christopher:`

`Reading package lists... Done`

`Building dependency tree`       

`Reading state information... Done`

`You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:`

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:`

`openjdk-7-jdk : Depends: openjdk-7-jre (= 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1) 
but 7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed`

`E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no     packages (or specify a solution).`

Comment: Try this:  `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jdk_7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb`  This will force the new java package to overwrite the file from the old package, which it is complaining about.

Comment: Posted the output, still can't run `sudo apt-get -f install`. (Thanks for all the help so far!)

Comment: Well, you could chase up the tree and start with `sudo dpkg -i  /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jre_7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb`

Comment: Apparently there is no such file.

Comment: Hm.  I would have thought that would have been downloaded prior to attempting the configuration.  I'm out of sane ideas here, as apparently you need to download the jre package before you can configure the jdk package.  You can download the .deb at [this link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/openjdk-7-jre/download)

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the file and tried to install it but encountered a fairly cryptic error message (added to post).

Comment: K - looks like openjdk-7-jre depends on openjdk-7-jre-headless, which you can get at [this link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/openjdk-7-jre-headless/download)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a circular dependency bug in OpenJDK7 for which a patch is [posted here.](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=641049)

Answer (score 0):

Install the tool `aptitude`

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Run `aptitude`

```
sudo aptitude
```

In the lower area you see a red line. Look at the proposals and choose a suitable proposal.